# Commerce file description as text only

Tags: commerce, files

I've got a shop selling downloadable product variations. I'd like to display the Commerce Files field description to anonymous users as text only.

Here's how it currently appears for registered users:

[image: commerce file description for registered users]

The field description visible is an active link...

--

Here's the current display for anonymous users

[image: anonymous users]

No description available

--

I can't find anywhere in the UI that allows for displaying the description without a link to all users. Here's the display options
[image: commerce file display settings].

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. ticking the 'display' box on the file field in the product form and settings appropriate permissions worked.